# How can i add a autoincrement to a column with a doctrinemigration?

Tags: php, doctrine

I'am writing a migration in Doctrine and i have to add a autoincrement to a column, but i don't find any information to do so via the changeColumn-method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$options = array('auto_increment' => true);
$this->changeColumn('table_name', 'column_name', 'integer', $options);
```

Comment: I had to use `autoincrement` without an underscore for this to work, but it did work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$options = array('auto_increment' => true);
```